# What is the problem with array.push implementation in chrome based browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, polyfills, core-js

I had thought `array.push` was a very basic function so I was surprised to see Babel polyfill `array.push` for Chromium browsers. I checked the MDN document for [array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and saw that it says:

[image: corejs-array.push]

I checked [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-array) document and its [implementation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.push.js) but it is unclear how it "fixes" the problem in Chromium browsers.

So what is the problem? And how are Firefox/Safari implementations different from Chromium's implementation? Checking the following output for reference.

```
The corejs3 polyfill added the following polyfills:
  es.object.to-string { "ie":"10" }
  es.promise { "ie":"10" }
  web.dom-collections.for-each { "ie":"10" }
  es.array.from { "ie":"10" }
  es.string.iterator { "ie":"10" }
  es.array.push { "chrome":"115", "edge":"110", "ie":"10" } //Only for Chromium, not for FF & Safari
  ...
```

BTW, to let babel not polyfill for `array.push` I have to add `exclude` to babel setting like this

```
     "useBuiltIns": "usage",
     "shippedProposals": true,
     "corejs": "3.33"
     "exclude": ["es.array.push"]
```

Comment: At the MDN page I can't find that the polyfill was specifically for Chromium browsers ..?

Comment: Right, MDN didn't mention the fix is for Chromium browsers only. But if you try Babel to transpile you can see that, only Chromium browsers get polyfill, FF and Safari don't.  I updated my question for that too.

Comment: The implementation has a link to a [V8 bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=12681), that's not very verbose, though.

Comment: Yes I saw that before I raised the question but what is the plain English for that error (my question)

Comment: "*My second question is if I don't want Babel to polyfill some specific feature/bugfix, how do I do?*" - you better [ask that as a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Bergi I Agree and actually I have figured that out but let me try to understand your answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is the problem?

Some engines (in particular V8) are failing the [*Array/prototype/push
/set-length-zero-array-length-is-non-writable* test case](https://github.com/tc39/test262/blob/2060494f280ba89d71a0f51d4ff171bafe476a05/test/built-ins/Array/prototype/push/set-length-zero-array-length-is-non-writable.js) of the [test262 suite](https://v8.github.io/test262/website/default.html). That's [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=12681), and *core-js* provides a workaround.

Now what does the test check for? A really obscure edge case:

- if you take an array and make its `.length` non-writable
- then proceed to call `.push()`, which would attempt to write the `.length` and fail
- but actually do not pass any arguments, so the `.length` doesn't actually change
- and if you still expect this to throw an exception

…then V8 lets you down: it doesn't throw the exception that it should throw but simply returns `0` (the length of the unchanged empty array).

Also there appears to be a second problem, with really old Firefox versions, from before [the feature of non-writable `.length` properties was introduced](https://whereswalden.com/2013/08/05/new-in-firefox-23-the-length-property-of-an-array-can-be-made-non-writable-but-you-shouldnt-do-it/) (10 years ago!), that it would not throw the expected `TypeError` but an `InternalError`.

> It is unclear how it "fixes" the problem in Chromium browsers.

The polyfill - just like any other polyfill - overwrites `Array.prototype.push` with [a conforming implementation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.push.js) that simply assigns the respective properties on the receiver. This includes the assignment to `.length`, even with an unchanged value, which will throw as expected. (Well actually it calls an [`array-set-length.js` method](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/array-set-length.js) to do that, which has to do the writability check explicitly in some engines).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me think about it before I accept it. About "It is unclear how it "fixes" the problem in Chromium browsers" what I meant was I didn't understand how core-js's implementation fixes the problem (because I didn't get the edge case in the first place). It is not about how polyfill fixes the problem. Polyfill replaces the default array.push, which I understood.

Comment: I have to say I don't see the value of this edge case. I also updated to my question to show how to let babel not polyfill it.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the problem?

When browsers allowed making array lengths non-writable as seen [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858381), it affected the `Array.push()` method since `Array.push()` adds the specified elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array. [If the array length is made non-writable, the array will not be able to update it. This causes an error.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length#array_with_non-writable_length) Unfortunately, with this addition, a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=12681) was discovered. [Core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-array) has added a [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.push.js) which is what you just came across:

> [properErrorOnNonWritableLength()](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/822c819ec65b98d1f705d9c89e8893fb04f6ea95/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.push.js#L15).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But does "Allow making array lengths non-writable" mean "making array lengths const"?

Comment: @Qiulang Yes. It gives you a fixed length array. You cannot add more to it once the max length has been reached. But what happens in the case of empty array with fixed length? See [sparse arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays).

Comment: What is "*this was not contemplated citation needed so when the bug was discovered, it had to be resolved*" supposed to mean?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I wouldn't call that a resolution. The bug in V8 is still open.

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I edited my answer but I guess your answer is more precise. 